# How to put an URL as node input in linux terminal

Tags: node.js, shell, terminal

I've had a problem when I was trying to input a parameter on my node application. When I try to input a URL with a special character it got split. I've tried this: `node [application name] [URL as parameter]`

If there is a "&" in the URL String the application

```
node [application name] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask_name=[exemple]&[exemple2]
```

In the application I got:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask_name=[exemple]
```

and the rest is gone. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your parameter has special characters you should put between "" or ''.

```
node [application name] 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask_name=[exemple]&[exemple2]'
```

or

```
node [application name] "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask_name=[exemple]&[exemple2]"
```